# Best practices in Ruby for loop

Tags: ruby, for-loop

I came across three ways of writing a loop.

```
the_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

- for loop 1

  ```
  for number in the_count
    puts "This is count #{number}"
  end
  ```
- for loop 2

  ```
  the_count.each do |count|
    puts "The counter is at: #{count}"
  end
  ```
- for loop 3

  ```
  the_count.each {|i| puts "I got #{i}"}
  ```

Are there situations in which one way is a good practice or better solution than the other two? The first one is the most similar to the ones in other languages, and for me, the third one looks unorderly.

Comment: The idiomatic way is 2 if the block is long, or 3 if the block is short.

Comment: Besides mentioned above: `(1..5).each`, `1.upto(5).each`, etc. And, `(1..5).to_a` will give you `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: @YuHao You could probably post that as an answer. That covers the question, to my mind.

Comment: Also, in the **for in** example the variable **the_count** will still be available after the end of the loop. But not in the block variants

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first option is generally discouraged. It is possible in ruby to be more friendly towards developers coming from other languages (as they recognize the syntax) but it behaves a bit strange regarding variable visibility. Generally, you should avoid this variant everywhere and use only one of the block variants.

The advantage of the two other variants is that it works the same for all methods accepting a block, e.g. `map`, `reduce`, `take_while` and others.

The two bottom variants are mostly equivalent You use the `each` method and provide it with a block. The `each` method calls the block once for each element in the array.

Which one you use is mostly up to preference. Most people tend to use the one with braces for simple blocks which don't require a line-break. If you want to use a line-break in your block, e.g. if you have multiple statements there, you should use the `do`...`end` variant. This makes your code more readable.

There are other slightly more nuanced opinions on when you should use one or the other (e.g. some always use the braces form when writing functional block, i.e. ones which don't affect the outside of the block even when they are longer), but if you follow this above advice, you will please at least 98% of all ruby developers reading your code.

Thus, in conclusion, avoid the `for i in ...` variants (the same counts for `while`, `until`, ...) and always use the block-form. Use the `do`...`end` of block for complex blocks and the braces-form for simple one-line blocks.

When you use the the block form, you should however be aware of the slight differences in priority when chaining methods.

This

```
foo bar { |i| puts i }
```

is equivalent to

```
foo(bar{|i| puts i})
```

while

```
foo bar do |i|
  puts i
end
```

is equivalent to

```
foo(bar) { |i| puts i }
```

As you can see, in the braces form, the block is passed to the right-most method while in the `do`...`end` form, the block is passed to the left-most method. You can always resolve the ambiguity with parenthesis though.

Comment: Thanks for the very insightful answer!

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that this is trade-off between *idiomatic Ruby* (solutions 2 and 3) and *performant Ruby* (using while loops, because `for …in` uses `each` under the hood) as pointed out in [Yet Another Language Speed Test: Counting Primes](https://bjpelc.wordpress.com/2015/01/10/yet-another-language-speed-test-counting-primes-c-c-java-javascript-php-python-and-ruby-2/):

> Notably, it should be mentioned that writing idiomatic Python and Ruby results in much slower code than that used here. Ranges bad. While loops good.

While it's generally encouraged to opt for idiomatic Ruby, there are perfectly valid situations where you want to ignore that advice.

Comment: The **for in** uses **each** under the hood

Comment: which means that `for` is even slower than `each`, contrary to what this answer seems to be suggesting.

Comment: Okay, I incorporated that into my answer. Thanks for pointing it out. I was thinking of `while`, not `for in`. My point stands: Use idiomatic Ruby as a default but be aware that it's slow.

Comment: But would you pick Ruby if you're that concerned about performance ? :-)

Comment: Rest assured that Ruby is always my first choice. That's why it's important to be aware of such trade-offs when speed matters. I know most of the time it doesn't, and it would be wrong to optimize early.

Comment: @awendt I think, generally the advise should be to *always* write constructs idiomatic to the language. Understandability trumps performance in almost all cases (and if it doesn't, then Ruby is often the wrong language anyways). That said, of course, there are cases to deviate from the rule. But this should be seriously considered on each case individually and only when measuring the concrete case. Advising to use the `for` form "because it is faster" in some strange benchmark is probably the wrong approach.