# How to create enumerable class without another enumerable?

Tags: ruby

I asked this same sort of question a few days ago and somehow communication didn't happen. I've restructured my question so that hopefully we can zero in on the issue I need resolved.

The issue is basically this: how do you create an enumerable class that doesn't just use another enumerable? As a simplified but fully working example of what I need to do, consider this class:

```
class MyClass
    include Enumerable

    def get_next
        return_val = rand.to_s

        if return_val.match(/33/)
            return nil
        else
            return return_val
        end
    end

    def each
        # ??????
    end
end
```

In this class, get_next calculates a random value. Then, if that value has two 3's next to each other, the method returns nil. Otherwise it returns the value. So you can run get_next over and over, usually for fewer than ten times:

```
myob = MyClass.new

while not myob.get_next.nil?
    puts 'got one'
end
```

In reality, get_next searches through thousands of data points. When it finds the next item, it returns a rather voluminous object. It is impossible for a MyClass object to slurp in all items into an array. It needs to get just one at a time.

In point of fact, my class works just fine as structured above. However, I want to implement this in a rubyish way.

So, given the working class above, fill in the blanks. What would go in each() to make this an enumerable class?

Comment: Take a look at the example for [`Enumerator.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerator.html#method-c-new) – calling `take(10)` only returns the first 10 items, although numbers are yielded in an infinite loop. Worth reading: https://blog.arkency.com/2014/01/ruby-to-enum-for-enumerator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyClass
  include Enumerable

  def enum
    @enum ||= Enumerator.new do |y|
      loop do  
        value = get_next
        raise StopIteration.new("nil") if value.nil?
        y << value
      end    
    end  
  end

  def each
    return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?
    enum.each(&Proc.new)
  end

  def get_next
    return_val = rand.to_s
    return_val.match(/33/) ? nil : return_val
  end
end

mc = MyClass.new
mc.each { |e| puts e }
#⇒ 0.9354594959902887
#  0.6425492923024724
#  0.24551401459676037
#  0.17117672854168786
#  0.15611540754420283
#  0.3914491388594509
#  0.40243662946930725
#  0.3792875585148314
#  0.11978219941961588
#  0.49891129730441874
```

Comment: Fantastic! Works just like I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> fill in the blanks. What would go in each() to make this an enumerable class?

The doc says [*"The class must provide a method `each`, which yields successive members of the collection."*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html). So you could just do that, keep yielding values as long as they're not `nil`.

```
def each
  while val = get_next
    yield val
  end
end
```

Demo:

```
irb(main):002:0> MyClass.new.each { |e| puts e }
0.9368650618038962
0.9784286059513836
0.9881624526762572
```

Another demo (to show a method from `Enumerable`):

```
irb(main):003:0> MyClass.new.map(&:to_f)
=> [0.6368065208805999, 0.6926393662295052, 0.9911564544581742, 0.35788099831068787]
```

---

So that's enough to make it "enumerable", in the sense of successfully mixing in `Enumerable` (and I don't think there's an official Ruby definition of "enumerable"). It's not clear from your question whether you actually need that, btw. If all you want is to go over values with `each`, then you don't even need to include `Enumerable`. All that does is give you additional methods like `map` and `select`. Even a `for` loop works just thanks to `each`, without including `Enumerable`:

```
irb(main):002:0> for e in MyClass.new
irb(main):003:1>   puts e
irb(main):004:1> end
0.7638166357043203
0.18409214000273166
0.39757329498164495
0.14658393540113002
0.948396753859117
0.3157122887487579
0.4804571082701993
```

(But note that `for` loops are generally discouraged: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263749/1672429), [[2]](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#user-content-no-for-loops). I'm only showing this to further demonstrate the importance of `each` and the unimportance of `Enumerable` for basic iteration.)

Comment: ...and if you want `each` with no arguments to return an Enumerator (just like stdlib enumerables do), add  `return to_enum unless block_given?` to the top of the method.

Comment: This implementation is not compatible with `next` contract, that expects `StopIteration` to be _thrown_ when there are no items to iterate. That said, this implementation is not compatible with ruby at all and might have many hidden glitches that will turn out to be a production run-time bugs later. The proper way to go is an `Enumerator` as I showed up in my answer, this is plain wrong and even worse dangerous.

Comment: @mudasobwa Huh? I'm doing exactly what the documentation says. And *"not compatible with ruby at all"*? Did you overlook the part where I demonstrate that it works? *More* than *you* do, btw, since your demo doesn't even use anything from `Enumerable`. And "`next` contract"? It doesn't even *have* a `next` method. That's an `Enumerator` thing, not an `Enumerable` thing. And if you do want a non-block `Enumerator` result, just add what mwp said. You even do that yourself (just longer). Then you'd also have a `next`, and it would do the `StopIteration`. Can you show an actual problem?

Comment: Sure. Try to make it `lazy`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Ok I just tried that and it worked fine. (It btw already is lazy, isn't it?)

Comment: Indeed, it works even with `take`. Turned out ruby constructs a proper `Enumerator` in [`Object#enum_for`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-enum_for). It’s not lazy, though. Please make a small change in the answer so that I could retract my downvote and put what this answer deserves; an upvote.

Comment: @mudasobwa What do you mean it's not lazy?

Comment: “It btw already is lazy, isn't it?”—I mean it’s not lazy in the ruby sense. `my.map.each { |i| i }` wont execute the latter `each` for each mapped value consequently.

Comment: @mudasobwa With "It btw already is lazy, isn't it?" I meant my answer, i.e., my `each`, as used in `MyClass.new.each { |e| puts e }`. What's the `my` in your example?

Comment: `my = MyClass.new`

Comment: @mudasobwa Ok, that works and yes, that's not lazy. Gives me an array. **Just like yours does.** So I don't know what your point is with this...

Comment: @mudasobwa Oh, I guess I misunderstood your request for "a small change". I thought you meant a change to fix something and I was trying to find out what you still wanted me to fix. I forgot that SO locks votes. I did make an edit now, adding some further thoughts.