# In Ruby, if I have an array, how can I replace any negative values with "0"?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Lets say I have the following array:

array_sample = [2, 7, 3, -5, 2, -6]

Is there a method to replace '-5' and '-6' with 0 (or any other potential negative values)?

I have tried the following which does not seem to work:

```
for i in array_sample
   if array_sample[i] < 0
       array_sample[i] = 0
end
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, because this seems very simple!

Comment: `i` is not what you think it is. Just insert `puts i`  below `for i in array_sample` to investigate.

Comment: Also, it's better to use `.map` or `.each` than for loops in ruby: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263749/8031815

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
array_sample = [2, 7, 3, -5, 2, -6]

array_sample.map! { |e| e > 0 ? e : 0 }
```

Response

```
[2, 7, 3, 0, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's another snippet:

```rb
array_sample.map!{|item| [0, item].max}
```

This replaces each array value with the original item, or 0, whichever is greater. If you want a new array that doesn't mutate the current array (good idea often), you can use `map` instead of `map!`.

Comment: Since the OP specifically asks for replacing, you should use `map!` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using map

```
array_sample.map do |int|
   if (int < 0)
      0
   else 
      int
   end
end
```

Comment: Yes, but use `map!` or assign it to a new (or the same) variable

Comment: `map` is the most ideal way to do it. But, perhaps try conditional expression? Say, `array_sample.map { |item| item < 0 ? 0 : item }`

Answer (score 1):

To directly translate your example to correct code, you could do this:

```rb
array_sample.each_with_index do |value, index|
  if value < 0
    array_sample[index] = 0
  end
end
```

But other answers may be more idiomatic.

Note that ruby doesn't iterate using numbers by default, like c-like languages often do. Most of the time ruby gives you back each item, not the index and then you have to look up the number. (It hides the index unless you ask for it)